# Correct way to access pg pool instance from typeorm connection

Tags: typeorm

Trying to access pg pool instance from connection. Found a workaround which is not official.

```
const pgDriver = connection.driver as PostgresDriver;
const pool = pgDriver.master as Pool;
```

Wondering if there is an official way to access it.
Links:

1. https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3491#issuecomment-456792285
2. https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/5831#issuecomment-704061863
3. https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/58fc08840a4a64ca1935391f4709a784c3f0b373/src/driver/postgres/PostgresDriver.ts#L53